# Spring JPA with Memory based Filtering

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

We are using Hibernate with JPA.

We need to write a @Query with a WHERE clause as below :

```
*WHERE last_action LIKE '%deleted%' AND ACTIVE_INDICATOR='N'*
```

However if I write this query as it is, it will do a Full Table Scan and will take a long time to complete ( because of the wildcards on last_action, indexes will be missed )
However because of the nature of the data, I know that if I run teh query with just one condition - WHERE ACTIVE_INDICATOR='N' - only about 100 rows will be returned. And it will be easy and feasible to do a regular expression match for the  remaining condition on last_action in Java.

Is it possible to do this without writing an additional wrapper method ?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create a special index which would work for LIKE statements as well (like **trigram index** in Postgres).
2. You can try changing the order of conditions (not sure whether Hibernate keeps it or you'd have to write a native SQL) so that the one with LIKE is the last one.
3. Or as you said - filter in Java manually. I don't think there's an automatic mechanism for this. It's too easy to do yourself.

Comment: Thanks. We decided to do this by adding extra methods with default method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your database should be smart enough to figure this out as well if you have up-to-date statistics. Maybe you just have to refresh the statistics to get good performance?